# What does // mean when it is used in a file path? (Classic ASP)

Tags: file, asp-classic, path

On this site I have taken over development of, it keeps using file paths for certain images like:

**/ClassicWeb//pictures/catalogs/world.gif**
or
**..//pictures/catalogs/cintas.jpg**

It doesn't appear to be an escape character because it is only used for one of the slashes.
What does the **//** (double slash) signify when it is used in a file path like this?

BTW this is a ASP site from years ago...

Comment: It's an invalid path. It _may_ work - if I remember right classic ASP just fixes it up.

Comment: The weird thing is that it works when the site is deployed to their dev server, but it won't work on my local machine. What's more is I can't find the .gif file on their dev server anywhere but in AppData/Local/../Temp Internet Files. So I am confused

Comment: Can you provide a code example? The answer may depend on whether these paths are in html tags, FileSystem object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Universal Naming Convention or Uniform Naming Convention, but UNC recording as \ComputerName\SharedFolder\Resource

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out, it maps to a virtual path, something like:

    \\123.456.789.0\pictures/catalogs/atlas.gif

So I guess you were right about it being a shared resource.

Answer (score 1):

In your example above, if it is generated by the ASP code then it more than likely contains a blank or null variable between the two slashes such as

```
/ClassicWeb/<%=PathNameHere%>/pictures/catalogs/world.gif
```

The variable `PathNameHere` is probably blank.

If that's the case the result will be

```
/ClassicWeb//pictures/catalogs/world.gif
```

which still works in Windows.

Comment: Can you explain then why the path `\ClassicWeb\pictures\` doesn't even exist? I use find in the ENTIRE computer and the only place I can find world.gif is in temporary internet files after I have loaded the site. Could it be a virtual directory that is not on the computer or something?

Comment: @AlbatrossCafe -  You need to supply the code that generates that image path. That will gives us a better insight as to why it is occurring.
You don't mention if the paths actually produce something or are just 404 links?
Of course I'm also assuming the paths are generated by ASP code and not hard-coded into your pages, is this correct?